# Spark union weird behavior

Tags: scala, apache-spark, unions, rdd

I' m experiencing a very strange behavior with the `union` method of the `RDD` class. And I can't understand why it happens.

I have a class, in which there are a `data` and a `filteredData` vars. The first one is initialized from a `textFile` and some other `map` and `filter`, the second instead as a `sc.emptyRDD[Point]`. Then I have a method which is this:

```
do{
  /**
  * here val lastFiltered is computed
  */

  logger.debug("Filtered "+lastFiltered.count()+" points")

  filteredData=filteredData.union(lastFiltered)

  logger.debug("Filtered so far "+filteredData.count()+" points")

  data = data.subtract(lastFiltered)

  /** here data is repartitioned **/
}while(/** here there is a condition which is equivalent to lastFiltered.count() == 0 **/)
logger.info("Preprocessing has filtered "+filteredData.count()+" points")
```

What I'm getting from the logger is very very strange to me:

```
 Filtered 13 points
 Filtered so far 13 points
 Filtered 4 points
 Filtered so far 4834 points
 Filtered 0 points
 Filtered so far 0 points
 Preprocessing has filtered 0 points
```

Of course the first two lines are exactly as I expected...but later everything looks very strange to me. Moreover, the `subtract` method over the `data` RDD seems to work fine (the counts are those expected).

Can anyone help me in understanding what is happening?

Thank you!
Marco

Comment: It is very strange indeed! Can you narrow it down to a reproducible example?

Comment: Well, I think that a good way may be to chose randomly some points from `data` to build `lastFiltered` for two or three times...